# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, inflate-exception

I'm trying to make an app that contains an ActionBar with 3 tabs: "Map", "Destinatiosn" and "About Us".  Basically i'm using ViewPager as main layout and for individual pager views i use Fragments.

- activity_main.xml

  ```
  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/pager"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
  ```
- MainActivity.java

  ```
  public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {   
  private ViewPager viewPager;
  private TabsPagerAdapter mAdapter;
  private ActionBar actionBar;
  // Tab titles
  private String[] tabs = { "Maps", "Destinations", "About us" };

  /***************************************************************************************
   * 
   */
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      // Initialization
      //tabs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs_titles);
      viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
      actionBar = getActionBar();
      mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

      viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
      //actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
      actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

      // Adding Tabs
      for (String tab_name : tabs) {
          actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name).setTabListener(this));
      }

      /**
       * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
       * */
      viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

          @Override
          public void onPageSelected(int position) {
              // on changing the page
              // make respected tab selected
              actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
          }

          @Override
          public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
          }

          @Override
          public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
          }
      });
  }

  /***************************************************************************************
   * 
   */
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
      return true;
  }

  /***************************************************************************************
   * 
   */
  @Override
  public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {


  }

  /***************************************************************************************
   * 
   */
  @Override
  public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
      // on tab selected
      // show respected fragment view
      viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

  }

  /***************************************************************************************
   * 
   */
  @Override
  public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, android.app.FragmentTransaction arg1) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub

  }
  ```

  }

I am creating a FragmentPagerAdapter class to provide views to tab fragments.

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        // Map fragment activity
        return new MapFragment();
    case 1:
        // Destinations fragment activity
        return new DestinationsFragment();
    case 2:
        // About Us fragment activity
        return new AboutUsFragment();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // get item count - equal to number of tabs
    return 3;
}
```

}

Every one of the items have a layout file with his activity class.

1. Map

   - fragment_map Layout

     ```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

     <fragment
         android:id="@+id/map"
         android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

     </LinearLayout>
     ```
   - MapFragment class

     ```
     public class MapFragment extends Fragment {
     GoogleMap mapa;
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {    

     try{
         if(mapa == null){
             mapa = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap(); 
         }             
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);          
         return rootView;
     }catch(Exception e){
         View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

         e.printStackTrace();
         return rootView;
     }
     ```

     }
     }
   - Destinations (just a Relative Layout with a Text view for now)

Layout

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ff8400" >

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Destinations Screen"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
```

class

```
public class DestinationsFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        Log.d("", "CESAR");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_destinations, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

- About Us (just a Relative Layout with a Text view for now)

layout

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#17df0d">

        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Diseñar la pantalla de About Us"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
```

class

```
        public class AboutUsFragment extends Fragment {

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about_us, container, false);

        return rootView;
     }
     }
```

The problem is that when I change from tab "About Us" to any other tab, the app stops working and crashes. But this doesn't happen when i change from tab "Destinations" to the tab of "Map" and backwards. This error came when I added the MapFragment, before that, the map layout was just a RelativeLayout with a text view and worked well. The Map works.

- Excption stacktrace

  ```
  04-10 00:35:23.070: W/System.err(16428): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class fragment
  04-10 00:35:23.070: W/System.err(16428):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
  04-10 00:35:23.070: W/System.err(16428):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
  04-10 00:35:23.070: W/System.err(16428):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
  04-10 00:35:23.075: W/System.err(16428):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
  04-10 00:35:23.075: W/System.err(16428):    at com.bikes.touristtest.MapaFragment.onCreateView(MapaFragment.java:22)
  04-10 00:35:23.075: W/System.err(16428):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
  04-10 00:35:23.075: W/System.err(16428):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
  04-10 00:35:23.075: W/System.err(16428):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.attachFragment(FragmentManager.java:1291)
  04-10 00:35:23.080: W/System.err(16428):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:672)
  04-10 00:35:23.080: W/System.err(16428):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
  04-10 00:35:23.080: W/System.err(16428):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:478)
  04-10 00:35:23.080: W/System.err(16428):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
  04-10 00:35:23.080: W/System.err(16428):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
  04-10 00:35:23.085: W/System.err(16428):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:550)
  04-10 00:35:23.085: W/System.err(16428):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:509)
  04-10 00:35:23.085: W/System.err(16428):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:490)
  04-10 00:35:23.085: W/System.err(16428):    at com.bikes.touristtest.MainActivity.onTabSelected(MainActivity.java:92)
  04-10 00:35:23.090: W/System.err(16428):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java)
  04-10 00:35:23.090: W/System.err(16428):    at com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl$TabImpl.select(ActionBarImpl.java)
  04-10 00:35:23.090: W/System.err(16428):    at com.android.internal.widget.ScrollingTabContainerView$TabClickListener.onClick(ScrollingTabContainerView.java)
  04-10 00:35:23.090: W/System.err(16428):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java)
  04-10 00:35:23.090: W/System.err(16428):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java)
  04-10 00:35:23.090: W/System.err(16428):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
  04-10 00:35:23.095: W/System.err(16428):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
  04-10 00:35:23.095: W/System.err(16428):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
  04-10 00:35:23.095: W/System.err(16428):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
  04-10 00:35:23.095: W/System.err(16428):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  04-10 00:35:23.095: W/System.err(16428):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  04-10 00:35:23.095: W/System.err(16428):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
  04-10 00:35:23.100: W/System.err(16428):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
  04-10 00:35:23.100: W/System.err(16428):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
  04-10 00:35:23.100: W/System.err(16428): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #7: Duplicate id 0x7f050040, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
  04-10 00:35:23.105: W/System.err(16428):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:296)
  04-10 00:35:23.105: W/System.err(16428):    ... 31 more
  ```

Comment: Post the entire exception stacktrace.

Comment: You can't use that `fragment` tag in the xml layout(*fragment_map Layout*) if it's going to be the layout of another fragment. Instead use the `MapView` class.

Comment: why you are using viewPager ?

Comment: Go to project property> java build path> Order and Export> set your android-suppport-v4.jar in top by Up button.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Android, google maps fragment and viewpager - Error inflating class fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17476089/android-google-maps-fragment-and-viewpager-error-inflating-class-fragment)

I am still working on implementing that solution, but it seems viable.